# Зависает RabbitMQ

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

После непродолжительной работы rabbitmq зависает. Не грузиться web морда managed plugin'а, воркеры не передают и не принимают сообщения.

При выполнении команды `systemctl status rabbitmq-server` пишет что все хорошо.
В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:**

Netstat выдал около 17.000 TIME_WAIT соединений, так что установил net.core.somaxconn значение в 20000. Время работы увеличилось, но в итоге все равно та же проблема.

Пожалуйста, подскажите что делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло увеличение максимального числа открытых сокетов ждущих соединения (net.core.somaxconn).

Netstat выдал около 17.000 TIME_WAIT соединений, так что установил net.core.somaxconn значение в 20000.

**Команда:** `sysctl net.core.somaxconn=20000`

**UPD:**

В итоге все равно все стало зависать. Проблема решилась обновлением зависимостей rabbit'a.

```
amqp_client 3.6.10  RabbitMQ AMQP Client
asn1        4.0.4   The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.4
compiler    7.0.4   ERTS CXC 138 10
cowboy      1.0.4   Small, fast, modular HTTP server.
cowlib      1.0.2   Support library for manipulating Web protocols.
crypto      3.7.4   CRYPTO
inets       6.3.9   INETS CXC 138 49
kernel      5.2 ERTS CXC 138 10
mnesia      4.14.3  MNESIA CXC 138 12
os_mon      2.4.2   CPO CXC 138 46
public_key  1.4 Public key infrastructure
rabbit      3.6.10  RabbitMQ
rabbit_common               3.6.10  Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client
rabbitmq_management         3.6.10  RabbitMQ Management Console
rabbitmq_management_agent   3.6.10  RabbitMQ Management Agent
rabbitmq_web_dispatch       3.6.10  RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher
ranch       1.3.0   Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.
sasl        3.0.3   SASL CXC 138 11
ssl         8.1.3   Erlang/OTP SSL application
stdlib      3.3 ERTS CXC 138 10
syntax_tools    2.1.1   Syntax tools
xmerl       1.3.14  XML parser
```

Comment: `ulimit -n` ещё поднимите

Comment: Ваша команда, кстати, только в этой сессии работает. После ребута сервера установятся дефолтные значения. Надо в конфиг прописать, чтоб послеребута применялось.